# Make CKEditor 5 accept <br> or inline styles

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

Lokking through the documentation of CKEditor5, I could not find instructions on how to allow `<br>` tags.

I read somewhere online that you can use inline styles like `style = "margin:0px"` but it strips those as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [soft line break feature](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter/issues/2) is on the project's TODO list. Please leave your comment in the GitHub issue so we can understand your use–case better and provide the best possible solution.

> Saw somewhere online where you can use inline styles like style="margin:0px" but it strips those as well!

Read why the editor does so in the [project's FAQ](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#why-the-editor-filters-out-my-content-styles-classes-elements-where-is-configallowedcontent-true). Anyway, I strongly advise you to use global styles sheets instead of inline styles because they are against the idea of the semantic content. All the more that your style is associated with the layout (margin, spacing), not the content itself (font color, font size). CKEditor 5 is a content editor, not a layout editor.